# Metadata of Calculated columns in HANA

Tags: hana, hana-studio

i am looking for any system table where the SQL or the expressions written in calculated columns are stored. Rather than opening each and every calculation view, deep dive using the lineage and check for expression in calculated columns.

Answer (score 1):

Calculation view is stored in XML format so there's no plain system table with expression for every column. XML representation is stored in _SYS_REPO.ACTIVE_OBJECTS table, column CDATA. With little XSLT code you can get parent nodes and get field name and node name where the desired expression is located. For downstream lineage (find sources of the expression) you should do some parsing of expression which may be not so easy.